# Ive this code working but the problem is that the visitor cant see the typing effect as it loads before the vieport .I am using this in elementor

Tags: css, elementor

this code loads before the viewport, therefore the animation is not visible to the visitors
please help me load this code when the text comes to the viewport. I'm using this in elementor custom CSS for a text editor and it working fine but loads while the page loads and not when the visitor scrolls down to view that section of the page.

```
.css-typing p {
    color: #5D5D5D; 
    font-size: 95px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30em;
    animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}
 
p:nth-child(2){
    animation: type2 4s steps(60, end);
}

p:nth-child(3){
    animation: type3 6s steps(60, end);
}
 
p:nth-child(4){
    animation: type3 8s steps(60, end);
}
  
p:nth-child(5){
    animation: type3 10s steps(60, end);
}


@keyframes type{ 
    from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2{
    0%{width: 0;}
    50%{width: 0;}
    100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes type3{
    0%{width: 0;}
    50%{width: 0;}
    100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes type4{
    0%{width: 0;}
    50%{width: 0;}
    100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes type5{
    0%{width: 0;}
    50%{width: 0;}
    100%{ width: 100; } 
}
```

Comment: You need a bit of Javascript - is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

The animation wasn't doing anything (at least in my browser, Edge/Windows10) because the parameter for width change did not have any unit - I think % was wanted.

To get the animation set only when the paragraph is within the viewport we can use intersectionObserver. This will tell you when the element enters and leaves the viewport and at those points we can set/unset the animation.

I am not clear what effect is wanted when there are multiple p elements so this snippet just sets them to animate when they enter the viewport and stop animating when they leave it. You may want to investigate animation-delay to stop them animating too quickly upon each other if the user scrolls quickly, or you may want to set different times for each p element depending on how many characters it has for example. Without seeing the HTML and further description of what is required it's not possible to tell, but this snippet should get you started:

```html
<style>
.filler {
  height: 110vh;
}
.css-typing {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.css-typing p{

color: #5D5D5D; 
font-size: 95px;
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width: 30em;
animation: none 4s steps(60, end) 1; 
}

@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="filler">PLEASE SCROLL DOWN</div>
<div class="css-typing">
<p>THIS IS SOME TEXT</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>THIRD LINE</p>
<p>FOURTH LINE</p>
<div class="filler">MORE SCROLLING POSSIBLE</div>
</div>
<script>
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
      entry.target.style.animationName = (entry.isIntersecting) ? 'type' : 'none';
    });
  };
const pEls = document.querySelectorAll('.css-typing p');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
pEls.forEach( pEl => {
  observer.observe(pEl, {threshold: 1.0});
}); 

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried using it but it didnt work in the elementor